# Foundation emails - import all styles

Tags: sass, gulp, thymeleaf, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation emails and I include following styles to app.scss

```
@import 'flags';
```

flags file contains all flags like this:

```
.flag-icon-bq {
  background-image: url(../images/4x3/bq.svg);
}

.flag-icon-br {
  background-image: url(../images/4x3/br.svg);
}
... etc.
```

And in my Thymeleaf where I generate the email I use following expression to assign proper class:

```
<i th:class="'flag-icon-'+${userCountryCode}"></i>
```

The problem is that when I generate the css via `npm run build` only used CSS classes go to the css. This is obviously detected as not used thus it does not go to the final CSS.

Is there any option to include all styles from import regardless of their usage.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I changed in `gulpfile.js` following:

```
function sass() {
  return gulp.src('src/assets/scss/app.scss')
    .pipe($.if(!PRODUCTION, $.sourcemaps.init()))
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: ['node_modules/foundation-emails/scss']
    }).on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.if(PRODUCTION, $.uncss(
      {
        html: ['dist/**/*.html'],
        ignore: [/\.flag-icon-\w+/g]
      })))
    .pipe($.if(!PRODUCTION, $.sourcemaps.write()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
}
```

Addition of `ignore: [/\.flag-icon-\w+/g]` did the job.